# Apache Sentry API for Policy Management

Tags: apache-sentry

I am looking for way to define policy for Role pragmatically. Is there any API available for Sentry ? Either REST/JAVA ?

Any documentation or link will be great help?

Answer (score 2):

Sentry exposes [apache thrift](https://thrift.apache.org) client interface, here you can find thrift api definition [sentry_policy_service.thrift](https://github.com/apache/sentry/blob/master/sentry-service/sentry-service-common/src/main/resources/sentry_policy_service.thrift). You can use it for client source code generating.

Additionally, Cloudera releases compiled client libraries compatible to Sentry Service, distributed as a part of CDH i.e.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sentry</groupId>
    <artifactId>sentry-provider-db</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1-cdh5.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

available in Cloudera's maven repository:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <repositories>
     <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample program using "sentry-provider-db" to get the permission details of a given hive database, (this program may not be defining policy for Role, but this program might give you an idea, to use other methods to achieve that)

```
public class ConnectSentry {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SentryUserException, LoginException {


        String userName=args[0];
        String databaseName=args[1];




        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.set(ClientConfig.SERVER_RPC_ADDRESS, "servernamexx.domain");
        conf.set(ClientConfig.SERVER_RPC_PORT, "8038"); //default port is 8038, verify this setting in configuration of Sentry 



        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.login.name", "userName");


        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "login.conf");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "false");




        conf.set(ServerConfig.PRINCIPAL, "sentry/<sentry-server-principal>");

        SentryPolicyServiceClientDefaultImpl sentryPolicyServiceClientDefaultImpl = new SentryPolicyServiceClientDefaultImpl(
                conf);


      sentryPolicyServiceClientDefaultImpl.listUserRoles(userName).
             forEach(rolesentry -> {//System.out.println(rolesentry.getRoleName());
             try {

                 sentryPolicyServiceClientDefaultImpl.listAllPrivilegesByRoleName(userName, rolesentry.getRoleName()).forEach(
                         allpriv ->{
                             String db = allpriv.getDbName();
                             String permission=allpriv.getAction();
                             if (db.equals(args[1]))
                             {
                                 System.out.println("found database and permission is "+permission); 

                             }
                         }

                         );

            } catch (SentryUserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             });


    }
}
```

Refer the below program to get idea about the available methods

https://github.com/apache/incubator-sentry/blob/master/sentry-provider/sentry-provider-db/src/main/java/org/apache/sentry/provider/db/service/thrift/SentryPolicyServiceClientDefaultImpl.java

Below methods and class might be useful for you:

public class SentryPolicyServiceClientDefaultImpl implements SentryPolicyServiceClient

public synchronized void importPolicy(Map>> policyFileMappingData,
      String requestorUserName, boolean isOverwriteRole)

Post a comment, if you need sample krb5.conf, login.conf and pom.xml